# 2 equal EFI bootloaders on the same EFI partition?

Tags: bootloader, efi

I want to use 2 VeraCrypt bootloaders side by side (for an encrypted multiboot environment). How do I prevent that the first is overwritten by the second? Is there a possibility to rename the first (or change the path?).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help: [rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/).

It's a boot manager, which scans EFI partition for bootloaders and runs it. In your case folder structure in the EFI partition could be like this:

```
EFI
|
|__bootloader1
|      |__boot.efi
|
|__bootloader2
       |__boot.efi
```

rEFInd wil find both of them and will allow you to choose which to boot.

Comment: Ok thank. Refind is a very good hind. But my problem is: how do I get "bootloader 2" into that struct? VeraCrypt always creates the same Bootlader. So I would have to get VeraCryptBootloader_1 along with VeraCryptBootloader_2.

Comment: I'm not familiar with veracrypt, but I'd try to move first created bootloader from 'bootloader' folder to 'bootloader 1' before creating second one. It can be done easily in linux - just mount efi partition as any other filesystem. In windows you can use 'EasyUefi'.